# How to handle exception and execute remaining statements?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Please find the below block.

```
for i in 1..acd.count loop

insert into customer_account_mapping select customerid,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)),cost from customer_master where customername=customer_name and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from customer_account_mapping);

insert into user_permissions select distinct user_id,sales_person_name,sales_mgr_name,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)) from user_permissions where sales_person_name=sales_person and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from user_permissions) and rownum<2 ;
commit;
end loop;
```

If error occurred in first insert statement how to handle it and execute second insert statement.

Comment: It would be helpful to format your code so that it is not one long line.

Comment: It is generally bad practice to commit after every insert.  Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

wrap the lines with `begin ... end ... exception` it's like try / catch

```
for i in 1..acd.count loop

begin 
   insert into customer_account_mapping select customerid,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)),cost from customer_master where customername=customer_name and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from customer_account_mapping);
exception when others then 
   -- handle the exception
end;

insert into user_permissions select distinct user_id,sales_person_name,sales_mgr_name,upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i)) from user_permissions where sales_person_name=sales_person and concat(upper(pcd(i)),upper(acd(i))) not in (select concat(upper(pcode),upper(acode)) from user_permissions) and rownum<2 ;
commit;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin



 WHEN exception type  -- handles 'division by zero' error
           ...

 WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors
      ROLLBACK;

END;
```

Put this code block after first insert statement.